# Quickly jump between two or more points in a PDF

Tags: windows, pdf-reader

When reading an ebook PDF with a hundred pages I need to jump quickly to different sections of the book and go back.

The problem is after I jump to that section there is no quick way to go back where I left off.

Is there a PDF reader for Windows that has that feature?

Comment: Did Adobe Reader's Alt+Left work for you? (See Josmh's original answer and my comment on it.) If not, consider editing your question.

Comment: The original question made sense. Josmh's original answer was correct, but might have been misunderstood. (Perhaps Tjipz read Josmh's answer up to "enter a page number to jump to" and felt it wasn't a helpful answer the original question.) @Random: consider reverting the edit and let Tjipz clarify the question if needed?

Comment: The edit only added a clearer question title which the OP is free to edit if it's throwing people off. Everything else is substantially the same. @bav

Comment: @Random: The original question seems to be about going back one step. The edited question sounded slightly more like asking for a bookmark feature. I see now it can also be read the same as the original question. (I guess I was preturbed the highest voted answer was answering something different than the original question, and it appeared like the question was changed to match. It doesn't seem so bad now, but still might possibly be interpreted multiple ways.)

Comment: OP should ideally clarify the use or non-use of bookmarks and/or page numbers @bav

Answer (score 2):

[Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/) supports bookmarks. They are in the left hand pane and can be added using the plus-icon. To jump to the page associated with a bookmark, double click on the bookmark. To hide/unhide the left hand pane, press F4.

Other than that, in Foxit Reader you may use the forward/backward navigation buttons in the toolbar. They function in a similar way as in a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing I can think of, even beyond ebooks on the world of fullscreen PC's.

Your fallback is to use the readers' find command with whatever unique sentence you were last reading, making sure you typed it verbatim before pressing < ENTER >

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading at a certain point, and then enter a page number to jump to or click on a section heading in the table of contents and jump to a different place, simply push `alt` + `<left-arrow>` to go back to the point you were at before you jumped.

Comment: This only work if know the exact page number I would like to jump to

Comment: Or if the PDF you're reading is professional enough to have section markers you can jump to. If you are just scrolling, you just want bookmarks, but that's not what the original question sounded like.

Comment: To clarify, in Adobe Reader, you can use View → Go To → Previous View to step backward through previous views. (Keyboard: Alt+Left. Toolbar: right-click, go to More Tools, check Previous View to add it the toolbar.) You would use Previous View *after* you jump somewhere (by entering a page number or clicking a section link) and you want to go back to where you were *before* you jumped. (If you moved through additional pages or zoom levels after your jump, you'll have to use Previous View to undo each step until you get back to where you where.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to add bookmarks. Adobe Reader doesn't offer this (similarly, most PDF readers don't offer it free); you'd have to buy the actual editor from Adobe to be able to write anything. But there are plugins you can search for (try "adobe reader pdf bookmark plugin"). [This](http://johnford.is/plugin-bookmark-a-page-in-your-pdf/) is probably a good one.

Answer (score 0):

[Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) a PDF app for Mac has a split screen like feature that allows you to open two different sections of the same pdf at the same time, so you could have the page you are on in the top section and in the bottom section you could have the page you need to jump to and it also has a feature to mark a page and then jump back to the marked page from any other page. It's a Mac only app though, so you will need to find a app that offers equivalent feature for Windows. Alternatively you could use two different PDF readers and then you can open the same pdf in two different apps and use the second app to jump to specific sections, while keeping the first app constant. Finally some PDF readers have a Back & Forward keyboard shortcuts that allow jumping back and forth between different pages, for e.g. in [Adobe](http://techinch.com/blog/jump-back-and-forth-in-a-pdf-in-adobe-reader)